# Press an Arrow key using a html button or simply press it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to press an arrow key using an html button. I have so far found only trigger or simulate events.

Like in jquery we have a .click() to have a mouse click, similarly I am trying to have a arrowUp() similarly for all arrow keys.
I am ultimately trying to implement this in an angular app.

Please help.

**UPDATE**

Need to fire an up arrow key or F1 key event like the .click(), using typescript/javascript.

If an F1 key event is fired it should open up some kind of windows help tab.
So in a page if an up or down arrow key is fired, the page should scroll up or down accordingly.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/ is the jquery keyboard version of `.click()` that you speak of but couol you please explain more what you are trying to do and why?

Comment: Like you want to simulate a keypress and have it fire??

Comment: I am trying to programmatically press 'F1' or any kind of a keyboard button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular you need to bind the html button to a variable using `ViewChild`

```
<button #myButton>
```

And in the controller

```
@ViewChild('myButton')
myButton: ElementRef;
```

Then you can call the event

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{ 'which': '40'}); //down
this.myButton.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can use the different keycodes for the arrows:

37-left
38-up
39-right
40-down

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwmcfgkn/4/

Comment: The Keyboardevent is not getting fired with keycode parameter in angular.

Comment: Do you have an event listener for that element or the window? you can use keydown event instead. You need both the listener and to fire the event.

Comment: Hey thanks, this works but the Keyboardevent like ArrowUp isn't getting fired within the webpage. Like for example I wanted to control a game by automating keyboard events.

Comment: The keycode is 38 for up arrow, it should work the same way, how you trigger it depends on how you are implementing the game  I'm glad to help, can you mark this as correct?

Comment: I have tried it with 112 and 38, it listens but it doesn't work, when F1 or 112 is pressed, the default action is to open a new help tab in Win10.

Comment: You should mark this question as answered, open a new question and provide the code you are having trouble with instead of talking about it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a built in key listener event handler like [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter), but it seems limited to just several keys like Enter, Shift Control as described in the [Github Page](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c7572ac1f9bbda59ba301dd330e6f64faf91b9e1/modules/angular2/test/render/dom/events/key_events_spec.ts)

However, you can use HTML's robust key event handler like

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
  }

  switch (event.key) {
    case "Down": // IE/Edge specific value
    case "ArrowDown":
      // Do something for "down arrow" key press.
      break;
    case "Up": // IE/Edge specific value
    case "ArrowUp":
      // Do something for "up arrow" key press.
      break;

    default:
      return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
  }

  // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
  event.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

This example can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), and the full list of keys, including arrow keys [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#Navigation_keys)

Comment: This only listens to events, it doesn't fire it programmatically.